# How to send byte[] through servlet java

Tags: java

I want to convert image into `byte[]` and send it through servlet.
I have converted image to `byte[]` but send it to client ??

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
    throws ServletException, IOException {

    String name=request.getParameter("name");
    File f = new File("/Users/shilu/MyProject/Chat/Photo/" + name);
    byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(f.toPath());
    //What to do now??
}
```

Comment: what kind of image ? png, jpg...?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the type of image as you need to specify the [**content type**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_type) that matches with your image type.

So here assuming that you want to send a `png`, the code could be something like this:

```
// Set the media type matching with my image
response.setContentType("image/png");
// Write the data
try (OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream()) {
    out.write(data);
}
```

Comment: The `flush()` is unnecessary though, as the implicit `close()` will also perform a flush.

Comment: @Kayaman I was wondering if it was needed or not, I don't see it clearly in the doc of [OutputStream#close()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html#close--) that it would be necessarily flushed on close even if by experience I know that it will, it may be implementation specific, don't you agree?

Comment: I'd be hesitant to say that it's implementation specific. I would say that a poorly designed stream would discard the bytes instead of flush them, but `OutputStream` doesn't specify any behaviour. However `FilterOutputStream` which is essentially the superclass of all custom `OutputStreams` does flush on close and state that it does so. I wouldn't bother writing overcareful code in cases like these, but YMMV.